# SQLServer (2000 & 2005) query for security/role info

Tags: sql-server, security

I need a query to display information about the users, roles and privileges within an SQLServer 2000 and SQLServer 2005 database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logins are here:

**SQL Server 2000:**
select * from master.dbo.syslogins

**SQL Server 2005:**
select * from master.sys.logins

Users (per current database):

**SQL Server 2000:**
select * from dbo.sysusers

**SQL Server 2005:**
select * from sys.users

From [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345522.aspx#_FAQ2):

> **How do I find all the owners of entities contained in a specified
>   schema?** [Before you run the following
>   query, replace `<database_name>` and
>   `<schema_name>` with valid names].

```
USE <database_name>;
GO
SELECT 'OBJECT' AS entity_type
    ,USER_NAME(OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'OwnerId')) AS owner_name
    ,name 
FROM sys.objects WHERE SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = '<schema_name>'
UNION 
SELECT 'TYPE' AS entity_type
    ,USER_NAME(TYPEPROPERTY(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '.' + name, 'OwnerId')) AS owner_name
    ,name 
FROM sys.types WHERE SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = '<schema_name>' 
UNION
SELECT 'XML SCHEMA COLLECTION' AS entity_type 
    ,COALESCE(USER_NAME(xsc.principal_id),USER_NAME(s.principal_id)) AS owner_name
    ,xsc.name 
FROM sys.xml_schema_collections AS xsc JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON s.schema_id = xsc.schema_id
WHERE s.name = '<schema_name>';
GO
```